# Why does sed outputs "char 53: unterminated `s' command"

Tags: sed

Why this bash script

```bsh
ssh $SERVER bash <<EOF
sed -i "s/database_name: [^ ]*/database_name: kartable_$ME" $PARAM_FILE
exit
EOF
```

output ->

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 53: unterminated `s' command
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The `s` command in `sed`, uses a specific syntax:

```
s/AAAA/BBBB/options
```

where `s` is the substitution command, `AAAA` is the regex you want to replace, `BBBB` is with what you want it to be replaced with and `options` is any of the substitution command's options, such as global (`g`) or ignore case (`i`).

In your specific case, you were missing the final slash `/`, if you add it, `sed` will work just fine:

```
➜  ~  sed 's/database_name: [^ ]*/database_name: kartable_$ME/'
database_name: something
database_name: kartable_$ME
```

`info sed 'The "s" Command'` includes the full description and usage of the s command.

Answer (score 16):

Missing `/` at the end.

```
sed -i "s/database_name: [^ ]*/database_name: kartable_$ME/" $PARAM_FILE
```

Comment: it was missing the `/` not the `g`, `g` is for global which may not be desired.

Answer (score 9):

In my case (an unusual issue) I had a \n in my sed command.
When I ran it in Jenkins pipeline or copy-paste it, it turned to be a multi-line command and it failed on this error.

The solution was to escape the backslash